# GCP server allow how many active user login at a time

Tags: server, google-cloud-platform

1.Total number of user login a GCP instance allow at a time?
2.How server resource get allocated among the jobs ran by concurrent user active any point of time?
3.Can we access google cloud server from any part of the world,how?If no,why?

Answer (score 0):

1. For GCE instances, the limiting factor on concurrent connections is the OS. For Windows server, without Remote Desktop Services (and associated licenses), the limit is 2. On Linux machines, the limit is determined by the [sshd_config file for MaxSessions and MaxStartups](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/sshd_config/)
2. Server resources are allocated based on the OS once again. For Linux, this can be by [restricting on a per-user basis](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ulimit.htm). As for Windows, there are different ways to enforce limits depending on the version you choose and how you deploy the server.
3. You can access the Google Cloud Platform and all the resources from almost anywhere in the world [(with some exceptions)](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2891389?hl=en) by access the external IP address of your instance, connecting to your Management console (console.cloud.google.com), or by running the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) from your machine